# Is it possible to find details about ingress/egress for Azure Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Is there any way to find out on our own where the ingress/egress activities are originating from/to (at least some details) for Azure Storage account?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to find out on our own where the ingress/egress
>   activities are originating from/to (at least some details) for Azure
>   Storage account?

You should be able to find this information out by analyzing contents of `$logs` blob container in your storage account. This blob container contains `Storage Analytics Logs`. You may need to enable storage analytics logging for your storage account as I believe it is not enabled by default.

You can find more information about storage analytics logging here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics-logging?tabs=dotnet.